# Cannot implement a custom operator via pattern matching

Tags: list, haskell, operator-overloading, operators, custom-operator

Basically, I need a function that accepts two lists and attempts to return a 2-list containing the head elements of both the input lists. Couple of corner cases: if both input lists are empty, the result must be an empty list. If only one list is non-empty, its head element must be returned wrapped in a list.

So far, I have tried this:

```
(+|+) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
+|+ [] [] = []
+|+ (x : _) [] = [x]
+|+ [] (y : _) = [y]
+|+ (x : _) (y : _) = [x, y]
```

Now, when I declare the operator as above, Haskell:

[image: Bad operator]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 3):

Operators are defined infix.

```
[] +|+ [] = []
```

If you really want to use prefix form, you can wrap it in parentheses, as needed for prefix form in other places.

```
(+|+) [] [] = []
```

For the definition, you might consider:

```
xs +|+ ys = [xs, ys] >>= take 1
```

Comment: @coderodde Maybe it's the same issue as `print []`, where Haskell can not infer the exact type of the empty list, but needs to in order to print it (an empty list of chars is a string and prints as `""`, an empty list of ints prints as `[]`). Try providing an explicit type as in  `print ([] +|+ [] :: [Int])`.

Comment: @coderodde that's a different question and should be asked ... surprise ... in a different Stack Overflow question if it's not already on here.